# Rotation to the right and left, like a pendulum - animation

Tags: android, animation, rotation

I am creating an application and I'm including an animation. It is a rotation to the right, and what I am looking for is that in the same way that rotates clockwise, rotate left and return to the starting point as a pendulum (all with the same speed), only one time.
This is the animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="50"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true"
     />
```

This animation begins when a previous animation ends:

```
AnimationListener animationInListener = new AnimationListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            tv2.setText("GAME OVER");
            count=count-count;
            duracionAnim=2000;
            tv1.startAnimation(animationRotateR);
            tv1.startAnimation(animationRotateL);
        }
```

I tried to make another animation with android: fromDegrees = "50" and android: toDegrees = "0", but not how to make it work one after the other.

I searched but did not find anything. Someone could help me?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. then update the question

Comment: Read this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.Builder.html